# Facebook login: code not sent

Tags: angularjs, facebook, satellizer

I've implemented Facebook login workflow in my website using Satellizer, and it's working fine. But for some reason, some users that try to login don't get the code parameter sent to the server, just the `clientID`, so I can't exchange it with the access token to get them logged in. Why is this happening?